# Do I need the base plus the travel health insurance?

Tags: germany, health-insurance, insurance

I am currently based in Germany, and I will be moving to the Netherlands. In January I won't be employed, as my current position ends by the end of the year, and my new position starts in February.

So I booked a trip to Cuba during my January. As I won't be employed in January, I won't have a health insurance as well.

My question is: Do I need to pay for a german base health insurance, *plus* the travel health insurance?

Ideally I would like to avoid paying an extra month of my useless health insurance.

Comment: What kind of health insurance do you have? The default in Germany is a public health insurance that takes a percentage of your salary, so when unemployed, you pay nothing (or technically correct a percentage of nothing). However, no German insurance will normally cover you when in Cuba so make sure you have an insurance for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

German health insurance will cover you even if you are unemployed, as long as you are still registered in Germany. If you have public health insurance, you will pay less or even nothing since you are unemployed.

German travel health insurance *usually* relies on you having regular health insurance. Travel health insurance will usually cover emergency care and a ticket back home, and little more. This is why travel insurance can cover you for a mere 10€/year.

Source: [cost of public health insurance](https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/german-health-insurance#public-health-insurance), personal experience

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would report yourself as unemployed for that month.

When reporting, show them the new contract starting in February.

If you have paid in the minimal amount (1 year), you may recieve unemployment money where you would then be insured (May depend on the reason why you are not working in January).

Otherwise when you are outside the country, nobody cares.