# Keeping health insurance between jobs in Germany

Tags: germany, health-insurance

I am relocating from Germany to the Netherlands, and also switching jobs. Between the end of my current contract and the start of my new one, there is a 1 month gap (January), where I would be technically unemployed.

When a job contract ends in Germany, in order to keep your "public" health insurance you have to either register as an unemployed, or pay for your health insurance out of your pocket.

I would like to have an active health insurance during the month of January, and I am wondering if I can do this without having to pay it directly.

Question: Would it be possible to register as unemployed just for that month, so to keep my health insurance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need the base plus the travel health insurance?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19501/do-i-need-the-base-plus-the-travel-health-insurance)

Comment: You have asked this question already ; see answer: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19501/do-i-need-the-base-plus-the-travel-health-insurance/19502#19502

Comment: The questions seem quite different to me, the first is whether I need to have an insurance, while this one is how to do that, or if it is a reasonable path.

Comment: It is the same person, same timeframe. Same lack of information: is he eligible (> 12), reason for 1 month in between, which may effect eligiblity. So same question. And he wants it in both.

Comment: If you are eligible, then report yourself unemployed before 31.12, showing that the old contract had to end at the end of the quarter and that a new contract starts on 01.02.20. In that way the unemployment will start/end automatically during January. All part of my answer that was not accepted.